# Can not seem to fetch the JSON data on my angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-http

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <body>

            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                {{ x.iata + ', ' + x.continent }}
              </li>
            </ul>

            </div>

            <script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
              $http.get("airports.json").then(function (response) {
                  $scope.myData = response.data.records;
              });
            });
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

**My airports.json lies in the same directory as my html file.**
**I also passed the url where the JSON file resides. But seem to have no luck. Please Guide**

JSON URL:
https://github.com/vedvasa/AngularPractice/blob/master/Assignment2/airports.json

**Do I need to host i on localhost, or a server???**

Comment: Your link is down. Have you pushed the file?

Comment: you should post the json here

Comment: "no luck". what error message do you get? (in the browser console, probably)

Comment: @JonyD yes. Please check the raw

Comment: what server are you using?  `$http.get` is a server call, it can't retrieve data "from the same directory as the HTML file" if the server isn't making that file available....

Comment: @Claies I hosted in ApacheTomcat local. Is that fine???

Answer (score 0):

You need a server and "airports.json" is put on server, then you use $http.get to call to server, the server should return "airports.json" data.